# array_agg function on Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill, array-agg

I need to use array_agg function like below.(It`s postgresql)

```sql
test=# select t2.c_no, array_agg(t4.contents) from table2 as t2 inner join table4 as t4 on t2.c_no = t4.c_no group by t2.c_no;
 c_no |        array_agg         
------+--------------------------
    2 | {kkac,aa,akkk,kkacd,kka}
   12 | {abc}
   21 | {kk,kkacaaad}
(3 rows)
```

But, I can`t find array_agg function in Apache Drill documents.

Do I need to make custom function of array_agg? Does the Apache Drill have a plan for array_agg function?

Comment: Check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6963

Comment: Thanks you for your comment :)

Comment: I tried to solve it myself now, but I ran into some problems, so I don't think it's a full answer yet that I would post here.
To fix my issues, I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919727/apache-drill-write-general-purpos-array-agg-udf