# Apache Drill: Write general-purpose array_agg UDF

Tags: java, apache-drill

I would like to create an `array_agg` UDF for Apache Drill to be able to aggregate all values of a group to a list of values.
This should work with any major types (required, optional) and minor types (varchar, dict, map, int, etc.)

However, I get the impression that Apache Drill's UDF API does not really make use of inheritance and generics. Each type has its own writer and handler, and they cannot be abstracted to handle any type. E.g., the `ValueHolder` interface seems to be purely cosmetic and cannot be used to have type-agnostic hooking of UDFs to any type.

### My current implementation

I tried to solve this by using Java's reflection so I could use the `ListHolder`'s write function independent of the holder of the original value.

However, I then ran into the limitations of the `@FunctionTemplate` annotation.
I cannot create a general UDF annotation for any value (I tried it with the interface `ValueHolder`: `@param ValueHolder input`.

So to me it seems like the only way to support different types to have separate classes for each type. But I can't even abstract much and work on any `@Param input`, because `input` is only visible in the class where its defined (i.e. type specific).

I based my implementation on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6963
and created the following two classes for required and optional varchars (how can this be unified in the first place?)

```java
@FunctionTemplate(
    name = "array_agg",
    scope = FunctionScope.POINT_AGGREGATE,
    nulls = NullHandling.INTERNAL
)
public static class VarChar_Agg implements DrillAggFunc {
    @Param org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.VarCharHolder input;
    @Workspace ObjectHolder agg;
    @Output org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ComplexWriter out;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override public void add() {
        if (agg.obj == null) {
            // Initialise list object for output
            agg.obj = out.rootAsList();
        }

        org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter listWriter =
                (org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter)agg.obj;

        listWriter.varChar().write(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void output() {
        ((org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter)agg.obj).endList();
    }
}

@FunctionTemplate(
    name = "array_agg",
    scope = FunctionScope.POINT_AGGREGATE,
    nulls = NullHandling.INTERNAL
)
public static class NullableVarChar_Agg implements DrillAggFunc {
    @Param NullableVarCharHolder input;
    @Workspace ObjectHolder agg;
    @Output org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ComplexWriter out;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override public void add() {
        if (agg.obj == null) {
            // Initialise list object for output
            agg.obj = out.rootAsList();
        }

        if (input.isSet != 1) {
            return;
        }

        org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter listWriter =
                (org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter)agg.obj;

        org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.VarCharHolder outHolder = new org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.VarCharHolder();
        outHolder.start = input.start;
        outHolder.end = input.end;
        outHolder.buffer = input.buffer;

        listWriter.varChar().write(outHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void output() {
        ((org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter)agg.obj).endList();
    }
}
```

Interestingly, I can't import `org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter` to make the whole thing easier because then Apache Drill would not find it.
So I have to put the entire package path for everything in `org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer` in the code.
Furthermore, I'm using the depcreated ObjectHolder. Any better solution?

Anyway: These work so far, e.g. with this query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(tbl.`timestamp`) AS start_view,
    MAX(tbl.`timestamp`) AS end_view,
    array_agg(tbl.eventLabel) AS label_agg
FROM `dfs.root`.`/path/to/avro/folder` AS tbl
WHERE tbl.data.slug IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tbl.data.slug
```

however, when I use `ORDER BY`, I get this:

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: UnsupportedOperationException: NULL

Fragment 0:0
```

Additionally, I tried more complex types, namely maps/dicts.
Interestingly, when I call `SELECT sqlTypeOf(tbl.data) FROM tbl`, I get MAP.
But when I write UDFs, the query planner complains about having no UDF `array_agg` for type `dict`.

Anyway, I wrote a version for dicts:

```java
@FunctionTemplate(
    name = "array_agg",
    scope = FunctionScope.POINT_AGGREGATE,
    nulls = NullHandling.INTERNAL
)
public static class Map_Agg implements DrillAggFunc {
    @Param MapHolder input;
    @Workspace ObjectHolder agg;
    @Output org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ComplexWriter out;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override public void add() {
        if (agg.obj == null) {
            // Initialise list object for output
            agg.obj = out.rootAsList();
        }

        org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter listWriter =
                (org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter) agg.obj;
        //listWriter.copyReader(input.reader);
        input.reader.copyAsValue(listWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void output() {
        ((org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter)agg.obj).endList();
    }
}

@FunctionTemplate(
        name = "array_agg",
        scope = FunctionScope.POINT_AGGREGATE,
        nulls = NullHandling.INTERNAL
)
public static class Dict_agg implements DrillAggFunc {
    @Param DictHolder input;
    @Workspace ObjectHolder agg;
    @Output org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ComplexWriter out;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        agg = new ObjectHolder();
    }

    @Override public void add() {
        if (agg.obj == null) {
            // Initialise list object for output
            agg.obj = out.rootAsList();
        }

        org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter listWriter =
                (org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter) agg.obj;
        //listWriter.copyReader(input.reader);
        input.reader.copyAsValue(listWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void output() {
        ((org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.writer.BaseWriter.ListWriter)agg.obj).endList();
    }
}
```

But here, I get an empty list in the field `data_agg` for my query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(tbl.`timestamp`) AS start_view,
    MAX(tbl.`timestamp`) AS end_view,
    array_agg(tbl.data) AS data_agg
FROM `dfs.root`.`/path/to/avro/folder` AS tbl
GROUP BY tbl.data.viewSlag
```

### Summary of questions

- **Most importantly: How do I create an `array_agg` UDF for Apache Drill?**
- How to make UDFs type-agnostic/general purpose? Do I really have to implement an entire class for each Nullable, Required and Repeated version of all types? That's a lot to do and quite tedious. Isn't there a way to handle values in an UDF agnostic to the underlying types?
  I wish Apache Drill would just use what Java offers here with function generic types, specialised function overloading and inheritence of their own type system. Am I missing something on how to do that?
- How can I fix the NULL problem when I use `ORDER BY` on my varchar version of the aggregate?
- How can I fix the problem where my aggregate of maps/dicts is an empty list?
- Is there an alternative to using the deprecated `ObjectHolder`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, unfortunately you've run into one of the limits of the Drill Aggregate UDF API which is that it can only return simple data types.[1](https://drill.apache.org/docs/developing-an-aggregate-function/)  It would be a great improvement to Drill to fix this, but that is the current status.  If you're interested in discussing that further, please start a thread on the Drill user group and/or slack channel.  I don't think it is impossible, but it would require some modification to the Drill internals. IMHO it would be well worth it because there are a few other UDFs that I'd like to implement that need this feature.

The second part of your question is how to make UDFs type agnostic and once again... you've found yet another bit of ugliness in the UDF API.  :-) If you do some digging in the codebase, you'll see that most of the Math functions have versions that accept `FLOAT`, `INT` etc..

Regarding the aggregate of null or empty lists.  I actually have some good news here... The current way of doing that is to provide two versions of the function, one which accepts regular holders and the second which accepts nullable holders and returns an empty list or map if the inputs are null.  Yes, this sucks, but the additional good news is that I'm working on cleaning this up and hopefully will have a PR submitted soon that will eliminate the need to do this.

Regarding the ObjectHolder, I wrote a `median` function that uses a few Stacks to compute a streaming median and I used the ObjectHolder for that.  I think it will be with us for some time as there is no alternative at the moment.

I hope this answers your questions.